# Table column colour to dominate row colour

Tags: tables

I want to produce a table in which certain rows and columns are coloured, but I want the column colour to dominate. In my example, the row colour dominates. How can I achieve this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{gray!30}}r}
\[
  \begin{array}{rrrgrrg}
  & & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
  \rowcolor{gray!70}
  2 & 4 & 3 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
  \rowcolor{gray!70}
  3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
  2 & 5 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
  3 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 0 & 1 \\
  \rowcolor{gray!70}
  2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
  \end{array}
\]
\newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{gray!80}}r}
\[
  \begin{array}{rrrgrrg}
  & & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
  \rowcolor{gray!50}
  2 & 4 & 3 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
  \rowcolor{gray!50}
  3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
  2 & 5 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
  3 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 0 & 1 \\
  \rowcolor{gray!50}
  2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: use `\cellcolor` on the intersections.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Since it is a simple thing, why don't add an option `columnsfirst` (or whatever) to the package to do that?

Comment: To ask a follow-up question, you have to open a fresh new question, with a link to this one. And, since my answer seems to solve this specific question, please consider to accept it.

Answer (score 10):

The `colortbl` package gives precedence to the color of rows than the color of columns.

But you can invert this behavior adding these lines to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@classz}
  {\CT@row@color}
  {\oldCT@column@color}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\@classz}
  {\CT@column@color}
  {\CT@row@color}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\@classz}
  {\oldCT@column@color}
  {\CT@column@color}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother
```

MWE (I've removed your `\hline`s since they look ugly)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@classz}
  {\CT@row@color}
  {\oldCT@column@color}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\@classz}
  {\CT@column@color}
  {\CT@row@color}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\@classz}
  {\oldCT@column@color}
  {\CT@column@color}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{gray!30}}r}
\[
  \begin{array}{rrrgrrg}
  & & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
  \rowcolor{gray!70}
  2 & 4 & 3 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
  \rowcolor{gray!70}
  3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
  2 & 5 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
  3 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 0 & 1 \\
  \rowcolor{gray!70}
  2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
  \end{array}
\]
\[
  \begin{array}{rrrgrrg}
  & & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
  \rowcolor{gray!50}
  2 & 4 & 3 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
  \rowcolor{gray!50}
  3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
  2 & 5 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
  3 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 0 & 1 \\
  \rowcolor{gray!50}
  2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @Psionman You're welcome. Remember that you can accept the answer to mark the question as solved. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Comment: This was just what I needed for a similar problem, great answer. Thanks

Comment: @beacon_bonanza Happy that this answer helped you!

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you can put instructions to color rows and columns (and also individual cells) in the `\CodeBefore`.

You can choice the order of these instructions.

Moreover, you won't see thin white lines (whatever PDF viewer you use).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccccc}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor{gray!70}{2,3,6}
  \columncolor{gray!30}{4,7}
\Body
  &   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
2 & 4 & 3 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 5 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 0 & 1 \\
2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{NiceTabular}


\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccccc}
\CodeBefore
  \columncolor{gray!30}{4,7}
  \rowcolor{gray!70}{2,3,6}
\Body
  &   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
2 & 4 & 3 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 5 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 0 & 1 \\
2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

This is also simple to obtain with new LaTeX 3 `tabularray` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{rowspec={Q Q[gray!50]Q[gray!50] QQ Q[gray!50]},
             colspec={Q[c]Q[c]Q[c]Q[c,gray!25]Q[c]Q[c] Q[c,gray!25]},
             }
  &   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
  \hline
2 & 4 & 3 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 5 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 0 & 1 \\
2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

*Note*, important is order of definitions of rows (first) and columns (last)!

Answer (score 0):

To have the color of a column dominant over the row, use `>{\cellcolor{gray!30}}c` instead of `>{\columncolor{gray!30}}c`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc>{\columncolor{gray!30}}ccc>{\columncolor{gray!30}}c}
  &   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
\rowcolor{gray!70}
2 & 4 & 3 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
\rowcolor{gray!70}
3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 5 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 0 & 1 \\
\rowcolor{gray!70}
2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ccc>{\cellcolor{gray!30}}ccc>{\cellcolor{gray!30}}c}
  &   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
\rowcolor{gray!70}
2 & 4 & 3 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
\rowcolor{gray!70}
3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 5 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 0 & 1 \\
\rowcolor{gray!70}
2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]